# How to use Ionic camera preview plugin properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to build a camera application using Ionic 4, but could not load camera-preview plugin. Application asks for camera permission,guess the camera is working, but i am getting a white screen only.Could anyone explain how it works and how to do it.

```js
 cameraOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: 50,
    camera: 'front',
    tapPhoto: true,
    previewDrag: true,
    toBack: true,
    alpha: 1
  }

  constructor(private cameraPreview: CameraPreview) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startCamera();
  }

  startCamera() {
    this.cameraPreview.startCamera(this.cameraOpts)
    .then(response => {
    console.log('camera running!' + response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
    console.log('couldnt access camera' + error)
    }) 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying it with IOS, then in config.xml under platform IOS section add the bottom 2 properties:-

```
<config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>Allow the app to access your photos</string>
</config-file>
<config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>Allow the app to use your camera</string>
</config-file>


const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  correctOrientation: true,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  ...useAlbum ? { sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY } : {}
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    // Do whats necessary
});
```

The **Camera Plugin** is a better option for using camera.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I need to use the camera in the application , not use the native camera. That is the reason why i opted for camera preview .

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

I added $background-color: transparent; to variable.scss

and set the background-color as transparent to the page i am using this plugin and voila it worked smoothly.